# How do I make ingress-nginx work without built-in LoadBalancer support for Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, internal-load-balancer

I'm new to Kubernetes and networking in general and I'm really confused about the `LoadBalancer` service. Let's say I'm using VPS that **DOES NOT** have built-in support for `LoadBalancer` unlike GCP, AWS EKS, etc (I'm using **[ssdnodes](https://www.ssdnodes.com/)** VPS). Let's say I want to use ingress controller, perhaps [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/), to proxy http/https requests into Kubernetes cluster. Now, I understand that Kubernetes services by default is "internal" only thus, I would need to expose services so that outside world can reach it - which can be done with `NodePort`. Ok, so since I'm using proxy service [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/), maybe I can just expose [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) as `NodePort` and point DNS record (AAAA) to it? This way, whenever I send request to, for example, "*mysebsite.com*" with AAAA record of "*123.456.789*", the nginx-ingress exposed to "*123.456.789*" will receive the request and properly pass them to associated services in the cluster.

**Am I following correctly so far??**

Here's what I'm also confused about. If my above theory is correct, why do I even need to use [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to "enable lower network layers" (which I don't know much about) servers without built-in `LoadBalancer` support? This makes me think that Kubernetes ingress is a lot more complicated compared to setting up standalone [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/) on a regular monolithic server. Which gives me an impression that in order for me to use Kubernetes properly, I only have few server options (GCP, AWS, and Azure). Also, what kind of [collisions](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/05/11/nodeport-dynamic-and-static-allocation/) is Kubernetes trying to avoid for port 80 and 443, as those will only be used for web application anyways? Is there even a way to "forcefully" assign `NodePort` IP to 80 and 443? If not, how can I avoid using port number in domain name, for example *http://mywebsite.com:30000/login* => *http://mywebsite.com/login*?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your description correctly, you are right, you don't need type:LoadBalancer service. Since you can use NodePort, you obviously can get traffic to your **node**.

I think the best in your case is to use "hostNetwork: true" for the ingress controller.

For more details, check for instance https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network